# Рекурсивный поиск. Нужно получить значения по двум ключам

Tags: python, json, рекурсия

Начал применять Python в автотестах.
Есть Json типа

```
{
  "someKey": {
   "anotherKey": {
     "oneMoreKey": [
       {
  "text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. ",
  "startTime": "00.000",
  "stopTime": "00.001",
  "id": "some"
},
       {
         "key1": {
           "key23": [
                    {
  "text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. ",
  "startTime": "00.000",
  "stopTime": "00.001",
  "id": "some"
}
           ]
         }
       }
     ]
   }
  }
}
```

1. Рекурсивно пропарить JSON, найти ключ "text" (сделано, функция - ниже)

```
    def json_find(d, key):
        if isinstance(d, dict):
            if key in d.keys():
                return d.get(key)
            return "".join([json_find(d[k], key) for k in d.keys()])
        elif isinstance(d, list):
            return "".join([json_find(x, key) for x in d])
        else:
            return ""

    print(json_find(data, search_key))
```

2. Найти что-то в значении ключа "text"
3. Если поиск успешен - получить значение ключа "id"

Помогите пожалуйста с 3-м пунктом. "Переклинило"

Comment: Не понятно зачем вы джоинте какую-то строку. Сделайте обычный цикл, из него возвращайте если что-то найдено.

Comment: цикл мне не подходит. там может быть любая вложенность и произвольная длина строки

Comment: Цикл вместо спискового выражения

Comment: поясните пожалуйста

Comment: Оформил ответом

Comment: ага. это понятно ) спасибо ). а как мне получить значение айдишнике если поиск успешен? )

Comment: Дописал в ответе

Comment: кра! получилось! спасибо вам большое )

Comment: Здравствуйте ) можно вас попросить глянуть эту тему? ) очень нужно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В целом по поводу рекурсивного поиска:

Не нужно джоинить результаты вложенных веток в одну строку. Возвращайте или найденный результат (один конкретный результат), или `None`, если ничего не найдено. По итерируемым последовательностям (спискам или значениям словаря) проходите обычным циклом, на каждом элементе вызывайте функцию рекурсивно. Если вернулось не `None` (что-то найдено) - возвращаете результат наружу.

```
data = {
  "someKey": {
   "anotherKey": {
     "oneMoreKey": [
       {
  "text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. ",
  "startTime": "00.000",
  "stopTime": "00.001",
  "id": "some"
},
       {
         "key1": {
           "key23": [
                    {
  "text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. ",
  "startTime": "00.000",
  "stopTime": "00.001",
  "id": "some"
}
           ]
         }
       }
     ]
   }
  }
}


def json_find(d, needle):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        if needle in d:
            return d[needle]
        
        for value in d.values():
            result = json_find(value, needle)
            if result is not None:
                return result
    elif isinstance(d, list):
        for value in d:
            result = json_find(value, needle)
            if result is not None:
                return result

    return None


print(json_find(data, "text"))
```

Результат:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
```

Значение по ключу `"id"` можно вернуть например вторым элементом, общий результат поиска будет кортежом:

```
...
return d[needle], d["id"]  # вместо return d[needle]
...
```

Получится

```
('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. ', 'some')
```

---

Если вдруг нужно будет найти все словари с ключом `"text"`, и из них вернуть значения, то заменяете обычную рекурсивную функцию на рекурсивный генератор, выводите результаты, например, циклом:

```
data = {
    "someKey": {
        "anotherKey": {
            "oneMoreKey": [
                {
                    "text": "Text1",
                    "startTime": "00.000",
                    "stopTime": "00.001",
                    "id": "id1",
                },
                {
                    "key1": {
                        "key23": [
                            {
                                "text": "Text2",
                                "startTime": "00.000",
                                "stopTime": "00.001",
                                "id": "id2",
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
            ]
        }
    }
}


def json_find(d, needle):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        if needle in d:
            yield d[needle], d["id"]

        for value in d.values():
            yield from json_find(value, needle)

    elif isinstance(d, list):
        for value in d:
            yield from json_find(value, needle)


for text, id_ in json_find(data, "text"):
    print(f"id: {id_}, text: {text}")
```

Вывод:

```
id: id1, text: Text1
id: id2, text: Text2
```