# Python. Json, рекурсия. не могу достичь ключа

Tags: python, python-3.x, рекурсия

Нужно добраться до ключа при помощи рекурсии.
Пожалуйста, прежде чем минусовать, прочтите пункт 3.1

1. Дано:

Json, см. ниже

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "contents": [
                {
                  "node": "strong",
                  "contents": [
                    { 
                      "node": "em", 
                      "text": "some NESTED cool text" 
                    }
                  ],
                  "startTime": "00.000",
                  "stopTime": "00.001",
                  "id": "id_1",
                  "text": " "
                },
                {
                    "contents": [
                        {
                          "startTime": "00.000",
                          "stopTime": "00.001",
                          "id": "id_2",
                          "text": "some cool text"
                        }

            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

2. Необходимо:

   2.1. Рекурсией брать из него 2 поля для каждого объекта: "text", "id"

   2.2. При условии, если значение "text" - пустая строка, - взять значение ключа "id" с этого уровня, после чего - провалиться на уровень глубже и взять там значение ключа "text"

   2.3. Вернуть (вывести и тд) полученный "id" и "text"
3. Что сделано:

   3.1. В этой [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1557996/Рекурсивный-поиск-Нужно-получить-значения-по-двум-ключам](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1557996/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BC-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BC) моей теме уважаемый **insolor**, за что ему большое спасибо, частично дал мне ответ но это слегка другая проблема, по этому решил создать новую тему. Собственно, сама рекурсия

```
def json_find(d, needle):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        if needle in d:
            yield d[needle], d["id"]

        for value in d.values():
            yield from json_find(value, needle)

    elif isinstance(d, list):
        for value in d:
            yield from json_find(value, needle)


for text, id_ in json_find(data, "text"):
    print(f"id: {id_}, text: {text}")
```

```
3.2 Вот такое не работает
```

```
import json
# from logic import *

# FILE = get_last_changed_file()
CHAPTERS_KEY = 'chapterId'
FRAMES_KEY = 'frameId'
searched_substr = ['  ', ' .', ' ,', ' :', ' ;', '( ', ' )', '{ ', ' }', 'keywords']

with open('../files/fullChapterArrayNEW.json', "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read())

def json_find(substr, d, needle):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        if needle in d:
            if substr in d[needle]:
                try:
                    yield d[needle], d["id"]
                except:
                    yield d[needle], None

        for value in d.values():
            yield from json_find(substr, value, needle)

    elif isinstance(d, list):
        for value in d:
            yield from json_find(substr, value, needle)


for i in range(len(searched_substr)):
    for text, id_ in json_find(searched_substr[i], data, "text"):
        print(f"substring: {searched_substr[i]} -//-, id: {id_} -//-, text: {text}")

f.close()
```

Comment: json сейчас не корректный, третий contents - это ключ, но он лежит в списке почему-то. Потом можно будет посмотреть.

Comment: Свой код лучше приложить текстом, а не скриншотом. Ну и не понятно как он соотносится с заданием - откуда-то взялась проверка needle на пробел (пробел - это не пустая строка, и needle - это не значение по ключу text, это сам искомый текст по предыдущей задаче), откуда-то взялся какой-то SEPLS.

Comment: вроде поправил )

Comment: щас свой код исправлю

Comment: `провалиться на уровень глубже и взять там значение ключа "text"` - на уровень глубже у вас означает провалиться в contents, но в contents лежит список, из какого элемента списка брать text - из первого или из всех?

Comment: да. там еще contents со списком. id  - общий для всех элементов этого списка и лежит "на уровень выше"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше в самой функции поиска ничего не менять (не добавлять какую-то дополнительную сложную логику), пусть она занимается только поиском нужного ключа. Наружу кроме значения ключа и id передаете еще вложенный contents. Все дополнительные проверки делаете снаружи.

Примерный код:

```
def json_find(d, needle):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        if needle in d:
            yield d[needle], d.get("id"), d.get("contents")  # <-- поменялась только эта строка

        for value in d.values():
            yield from json_find(value, needle)

    elif isinstance(d, list):
        for value in d:
            yield from json_find(value, needle)


data = {
    "data": [
        {
            "contents": [
                {
                    "node": "strong",
                    "contents": [{"node": "em", "text": "some NESTED cool text"}],
                    "startTime": "00.000",
                    "stopTime": "00.001",
                    "id": "id_1",
                    "text": " ",
                },
                {
                    "contents": [
                        {
                            "node": "strong",
                            "startTime": "00.000",
                            "stopTime": "00.001",
                            "id": "id_2",
                            "text": "some cool text",
                        }
                    ]
                },
            ]
        }
    ]
}

for text, id_, contents in json_find(data, "text"):
    # print(f"id: {id_}, text: {text}, contents: {contents}")
    if text == " " and contents:  # Текст равен пустой строке и contents не пустой
        # Дальше из contents вытаскиваете то что вам нужно, для примера - содержимое ключа text первого элемента
        print(contents[0]["text"])
```

Вывод:

```
some NESTED cool text
```

Comment: спасибо-преспасибо )